# OpenCV convert CV_8U to CV_64F

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to convert a grayscale image to the type CV64F. From the OpenCv documentation I have understood that a grayscale image is of the type CV_8U. I have also found that imshow plots different types differently, hence I need to divide by 255 before converting. But after converting the image I still get many saturated pixels.

I am using this image, saved as a jpg: 
http://www.ele.uri.edu/~hansenj/projects/ele585/lab2/cameraman.gif

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    Mat I, input_image;
    string path = "C:/<your_path>/camera_man.jpg";
    input_image = imread(path.c_str(), 0); // Read the file as grayscale

    imshow("Original", input_image);

    // Convert image to CV_64F
    input_image *= (double) 1 / 255;
    input_image.convertTo(I, CV_64F);
    imshow("Converted", I);

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do this:

```
input_image *= (double) 1 / 255;   // (1)
input_image.convertTo(I, CV_64F);  // (2)
```

You are dividing each value in a `CV_8UC1` matrix by 255 in (1), so each pixel will be:

```
new_value = static_cast<uchar>(old_value / 255)
```

so that `new_value` can have only values `0` for `0 <= old_value < 255`, and `1` for `old_value = 255`. Then the conversion is applied in (2) on truncated values.

So, you need either to first convert to `CV_64FC1` and then divide:

```
input_image.convertTo(I, CV_64F);
I *= (double)1 / 255;
```

or apply scaling directly during the conversion:

```
input_image.convertTo(I, CV_64F, 1.0 / 255.0);
```